# Django zappa 403 forbidden error and net:: Err_Aborted

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to deploy *vuejs*/frontend & *django*(python)/backend webapp with *AWS Lambda* using *zappa*. I have all of my static files in an S3 bucket. 
Whenever I try to view it in the browser, the page is completely blank and I am getting these errors in the console:

> GET https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/static/webpack_bundles/static/js/app.3122315aa5664adf.js 403 (Forbidden)
>   GET https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/static/webpack_bundles/static/css/app.b161c29d6c5fa852dc6887b62955427e6.css net::ERR_ABORTED
>   GET https://7exa5465ef451.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico 403 ()

Answer (score 0):

By default, S3 doesn't allow public access to it's content for security reasons. There are multiple ways to change that, by either setting public permissions on each individual object, or by applying a bucket policy.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html has additional details on how to control access to S3.

A specific public bucket policy example could look like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Taken from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2

In general, i would recommend serving website data such as that through Cloudfront, in which case, you can specifically allow Cloudfront to access the S3 data using a policy such as

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Id":"PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Sid":" Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be"},
       "Action":"s3:GetObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
     }
   ]
}
```

Taken from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-6

Comment: Thanks for the info, you saved me a lot of time, but some of my CSS(mainly fonts and images) aren't loading from CloudFront.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO as links change or go dead over time. You need to form your own answer or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @colde Yea these are the errors: map-image.f40ed5b.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
header-bg.e2d2a51.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
SverigeScriptClean_Demo.6f26ea8.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
FogtwoNo5.2cf6f1e.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Handlee-Regular.64bcfe1.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: @DewonClark 404 means the file isn't there. So either it didn't get uploaded, or some part of the URL is incorrect. Maybe your deployment process doesn't upload the webpack assets consistently?

Comment: @colde It may be a webpack issue. Its like half of my CSS files aren't loading.

Comment: @DewonClark Yeah, i would check the webpack debug output to see if something there is avry. Btw, if the answer helped you out, i would appreciate if you marked it as answered :)

Comment: @colde I made some changes in my AWS Lambda enviornment as it pertains to the zappa enviornment and now I am back to the blank page with a https://www.example.com/favicon.ico 400()

Comment: @colde Is it possible that my webapp is too large for AWS Lambda?

Comment: @DewonClark Totally. However, remember that you can change the default maximum runtime for Lambda, which might not be enough to execute some functions. Also, since everytime it coldstarts it has to load the entire app, you might want to focus on minimizing it.

Comment: @colde I tried to minimize it by using the slim_handler: true, unfortunately it raised a few errors. So I switched it back to false. I might just undeploy it and start over.

Comment: I have minimized it by excluding a few of my folders. I am just trying to figure out how to get the rest of my css to show up in the browser, and how to access the django admin from my custom domain.